# Effectively Lorentz-invariant interacting Lagrangians in solid state?

Tags: special-relativity, solid-state-physics, lorentz-symmetry

Are there any known examples in solid state physics when an essentially non-relativistic system in certain regime may be described by a relativistically invariant Lagrangian with an interaction?

Please note that I'm asking for something more than just the linear dispersion relation for the free theory plus some interaction. For example, a typical example is a system, described by the following Hamiltonian ($\hbar=1$)
\begin{equation}\label{eq:hamilt}
    H=\sum\limits_{\mathbf{k}}\Psi^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}}v|\mathbf{p}|\hat{\sigma}_{\mathbf{p}}\Psi_{\mathbf{p}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{\mathbf{p}}\sum\limits_{\mathbf{q}}\sum\limits_{\mathbf{q'}}\Psi^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{p}}\Psi_{\mathbf{q}}\frac{2\pi e^2}{|\mathbf{p}|}\Psi^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{q'}-\mathbf{p}}\Psi_{\mathbf{q'}},
\end{equation}
where $\hat{\sigma}_{\mathbf{p}}=\boldsymbol{\sigma}\cdot\mathbf{p}/|\mathbf{p}|=|\mathbf{p}|^{-1}(p_x\sigma_x+p_y\sigma_y)$ and $\sigma_{x,y}$ are Pauli matrices. 
Here the free term is 'Lorentz-invariant' while the second is not. However, even if we replace the second term by its 'proper' version stemming from the QED, the resulting Lagrangian shall not be 'Lorentz-invariant', since the "speeds of light" would be different for these two terms. In the free term, it is the speed of fermionic excitations, while in the interaction term it is the actual speed of light.

So I'm wondering if there are known instances of "effective Lorentz invariance" in the sense of the action containing an interaction term being invariant under the "Lorentz transformations"?